# Seeking help copying a database to another domain

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I can't seem to figure out how to simply copy a wordpress database from one domain to another using phpmyadmin. One domain has a WP site. The other domain has a fresh WP install and no content. I simply want to copy (but not mess with) the database from the first site and have it completely replace the fresh install on the second--essentially duplicating the website. T

he only way I see so far is to import the database into the second site, but in doing so, there are a a lot of tables that already exist and all sorts of edits to the sql file needed. Is there a plugin or method for simply replacing the second site's database with the first site's database in one quick easy shot? I do not want to just point the second domain at the first, but rather create a replica database on site on the second site.

Does this make sense?

Comment: 1. Export db from first site. 2. Find & replace old domain with new one. 3. Create a new db on second site & import the db.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin may be exactly what you're after:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Otherwise, the steps I usually take are;

1. export entire db sql from original site via phpmyadmin
2. load sql file into dreamweaver or any text editor with search/replace functionality
3. replace all instances of original domain with new domain, save as new sql file
4. go into phpmyadmin on new domain, DROP all tables in new database
5. import new sql file & test